# why plugin red audio jack in green audio jack does not work

Tags: audio

This may be silly question for most of you, but i always wondered, lets say we have a pc, and a phone, why when you connect the output jack of your phone, into the input jack of the pc (the red/blue input) it does not work?
I mean the both analog right? why dosnt the output jack behaves like a microphone or something?
My question is not restricted to phone and pc combination only, it's for any 2 terminals with input/ouput audio jacks.